# How to in Store View setting free shipping Amount

Tags: magento2.2, shipping, shipping-methods, magento2.2.2, magento2.2.3

we hope is USA is setting free shipping Amount is $10, AUS amount is $20. it can do that?

Magento 2.2.X
please help

Comment: did you mean free shipping amount should be based on country ?

Comment: Yes. Isn't All Store View using same amount . We want different amount for Store View. @Pawan

Comment: Hello @rigu, Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to override model [you can try this](https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/) usin custom module.

You need to override below model:

```
MagentoRoot/vendor\magento\module-offline-shipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping.php
```

In the above model you need to override `collectRates` method.
You can add below code

```
    $id =  $request->getDestCountryId();//give you country
    $total = $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();// cart total 

    if($id=='US' && $total>=10){
        $freeShip = true;
    }elseif($id=='AU' && $total>=20){
        $freeShip = true;
    }else{
        $freeShip = false;
    }
```

After that in result Append you can check `$freeShip` is true or not, like:

```
if($freeShip){
   $result->append($method);
}
```

Above code will show free shipping only if Your condition met.
You can also Add Store view code in above

Hope it will help.

**Update I**

If you don't want to add all country, we can add a default condition which will work for all country if subtotal is greater than config value.

```
$id =  $request->getDestCountryId();//give you country
$total = $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();// cart total 

if($id=='US' && $total>=10){
    $freeShip = true;
}elseif($id=='AU' && $total>=20){
    $freeShip = true;
}elseif($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData(
        'free_shipping_subtotal'
    )){
    $freeShip = true;
}
else{
    $freeShip = false;
}
```

Please let me know if you still have any issue.

Comment: i'm testing. i will tell you 10mins after. thank you^^ @Pawan

Comment: for test you can directly put code in original file.

Comment: i getting error to compile , updated in original post. @Pawan

Comment: could you please share whole file code ?

Comment: it seems you have added code before "collectRates" methods,

Comment: updated and compiled. but not showing free shipping , when chooes us or au @Pawan

Comment: you need to change "$result->append($method);" with if($freeShip){
   $result->append($method);
}

Comment: you added condition but not checked before Result .

Comment: i'm testing. i will tell you 5mins after. thank you^^"" @Pawan

Comment: updated the file in original post. ,not showing still, when choose United States, zip code:1. @Pawan

Comment: testing again miss the step @Pawan

Comment: There will no change in "_updateFreeMethodQuote" .

Comment: updated the full code in original post.but not working when choose Australia ZIP:61 @Pawan

Comment: it is working fine at my end, what admin setting for free shipping you have at the moment ?

Comment: can i ask your full code with me is same? and my step is edit code > and then 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

or need to php bin/magento module:enable ?@Pawan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76671/discussion-between-pawan-and-rigu).

Comment: Rigu, did my solution work for you ?

Comment: you gave me the code is working , but becoming > admin > shipping > free shipping Minimum Order Amount are not working for others country. Need add all country in the code @Pawan

Comment: Hello @rigu, have you achieve free shipping Or still have any issue ?